# rotate sphere in three.js so that mapped image of globe matches GeoJSON that is also shown in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geojson

I have created a globe in three.js and am using an image mapped to the sphere.

On top of this, I'm using the [ThreeGeoJSON library](https://github.com/jdomingu/ThreeGeoJSON) to render geojson data.

However the geographies don't match up. 
[image: three.js globe]

I need to rotate the globe with the mapped image so that they align, but I can't figure out how to do so. I tried setting a quaternion variable and rotating based on that, but can't get it working. Any help or pointers would be very much appreciated.

Here you can see a working version of what I've done so far:
http://bl.ocks.org/jhubley/8450d7b0df0a4a9fd8ce52d1775515d5

All of the code, images, data here:
https://gist.github.com/jhubley/8450d7b0df0a4a9fd8ce52d1775515d5

I've also pasted the index.html below.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>ThreeGeoJSON</title>

            <script src="threeGeoJSON.js"></script>

            <!-- Three.js library, movement controls, and jquery for the geojson-->
            <script src="three.min.js"></script>
            <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
              var width  = window.innerWidth,
                height = window.innerHeight;

              // Earth params
              var radius   = 9.99,
                segments = 32,
                rotation = 0 ;

                //New scene and camera
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, width / height, 0.01, 1000);
                camera.position.z = 1;
                camera.position.x = -.2;
                camera.position.y = .5;

                //New Renderer
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(width, height);
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                //Add lighting
                scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333));

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xe4eef9, .7);
                light.position.set(12,12,8);
                scene.add(light);

                var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
                quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ), Math.PI / 2 );



                var sphere = createSphere(radius, segments);
                //sphere.rotation.y = rotation;
                sphere.rotation = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion( quaternion );

                scene.add(sphere)

                //Create a sphere to make visualization easier.
                var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 32, 32);
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    //wireframe: true,
                    //transparent: true
                });

                function createSphere(radius, segments) {
                  return new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments),
                    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                      map:         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('relief.jpg'),
                      bumpMap:     THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('elev_bump_4k.jpg'),
                      bumpScale:   0.005,
                      specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('wateretopo.png'),
                      specular:    new THREE.Color('grey')
                    })
                  );
                }

                var clouds = createClouds(radius, segments);
                clouds.rotation.y = rotation;
                scene.add(clouds)

                function createClouds(radius, segments) {
                  return new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius + .003, segments, segments),
                    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                      map:         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('n_amer_clouds.png'),
                      transparent: true
                    })
                  );
                }

                //Draw the GeoJSON
                var test_json = $.getJSON("countries_states.geojson", function(data) {

                    drawThreeGeo(data, 10, 'sphere', {
                        color: 'red'
                    })
                });

                //Draw the GeoJSON loggerhead data
                var test_json = $.getJSON("loggerhead-distro-cec-any.json", function(data) {
                    drawThreeGeo(data, 10, 'sphere', {
                        color: 'blue'
                    })
                });

                //Set the camera position
                camera.position.z = 30;

                //Enable controls
                var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

                //Render the image
                function render() {
                    controls.update();
                    requestAnimationFrame(render);
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                }

                render();
            </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ancient r66, I used r81 (just replaced `three.min.js`). I modified your `createSphere()` function a bit, and seems it's working.

```
        function createSphere(radius, segments) {
            var sphGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments);
            sphGeom.rotateY(THREE.Math.degToRad(-90));
            return new THREE.Mesh(
                sphGeom,
                new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    map:         new THREE.TextureLoader().load('relief.jpg'),
                    bumpMap:     new THREE.TextureLoader().load('elev_bump_4k.jpg'),
                    bumpScale:   0.005,
                    specularMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('wateretopo.png'),
                    specular:    new THREE.Color('grey')
                })
            );
        }
```

The only thing I did was to rotate the sphere's geometry around Y-axis at -90 degrees. The result is [here](http://west77.ru/content/geoJSON/index.html)

[image: ORBIS TERRARVM]